# memset() not setting memory in c

Tags: c, memset

I apologize if my formatting is incorrect as this is my first post, I couldn't find a post on the site that dealt with the same issue I am running into.  I'm using plain C on ubuntu 12.04 server.  I'm trying to concatenate several strings together into a single string, separated by Ns.  The string sizes and space between strings may vary, however.  A struct was made to store the positional data as several integers that can be passed to multiple functions:

```
typedef struct pseuInts {  
    int pseuStartPos;  
    int pseuPos;  
    int posDiff;  
    int scafStartPos;  
} pseuInts;
```

As well as a string struct:

```
typedef struct string {  
    char *str;  
    int len;  
} myString;
```

Since there are break conditions for the concatenated string multiple nodes of a dynamically linked list were assembled containing an identifier and the concatenated string:

```
typedef struct entry {  
    myString title;  
    myString seq;  
    struct entry *next;  
} entry;
```

The memset call is as follows:

```
} else if ((*pseuInts)->pseuPos != (*pseuInts)->scafStartPos) {  
    (*pseuEntry)->seq.str = realloc ((*pseuEntry)->seq.str, (((*pseuEntry)->seq.len) + (((*pseuInts)->scafStartPos) - ((*pseuInts)->pseuPos)))); //realloc the string being extended to account for the Ns  
    memset (((*pseuEntry)->seq.str + ((*pseuEntry)->seq.len)), 'N', (((*pseuInts)->scafStartPos) - ((*pseuInts)->pseuPos))); //insert the correct number of Ns
    (*pseuEntry)->seq.len += (((*pseuInts)->scafStartPos) - ((*pseuInts)->pseuPos)); //Update the length of the now extended string  
    (*pseuInts)->pseuPos += (((*pseuInts)->scafStartPos) - ((*pseuInts)->pseuPos)); //update the position values  
}
```

These are all being dereferenced as this else if decision is in a function being called by a function called from main, but the changes to the pseuEntry struct need to be updated in main so as to be passed to another function for further processing.
I've double checked the numbers being used in pseuInts by inserting some printf commands and they are correct in the positioning of how many Ns need to be added, even as they change between different short strings.  However, when the program is run the memset only inserts Ns the first time it's called.  IE:

GATTGT and TAATTTGACT are separated by 4 spaces and they become:
GATTGTNNNNTAATTTGACT

The second time it is called on the same concatenated string it doesn't work though.  IE:
TAATTTGACT and TCTCC are separated by 6 spaces so the long string should become:

GATTGTNNNNTAATTTGACTNNNNNNTCTCC
but it only shows:
GATTGTNNNNTAATTTGACTTCTCC

I've added printfs to display the concatenated string immediately before and after the memset and the they are identical in output.
Sometimes the insertion is adding extra character spaces, but not initializing them so they print nonsense (as would be expected).  IE:

GAATAAANNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN¬GCTAATG
should be
GAATAAANNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNGCTAATG

I've switched the memset with a for or a while loop and I get the same result.  I used an intermediate char * to realloc and still get the same result.  I'm looking for for suggestions as to where I should look to try and detect the error.

Comment: Great description of the problem, just hard to see problem with all the dereferencing going on.  Maybe easier to troubleshoot if you can provide enough minimal code so that someone can compile, build, run it?  Easier to see what is going on.  [sscce](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: This stands no chance of compiling. `pseuInts` is a *type* in the first code block, and a *variable* in the last code block.

Comment: Curious - what would be wrong with using `pseuInts.pseuPos` instead of `(*pseuInts)->pseuPos`? (et. al.)

Comment: Since I only use one set of pseuInts that I update constantly through execution I decalred it as:  

    pseuInts *curPseuInts = malloc (sizeof (*curPseuInts));  

when it first appeared then passed it to these functions:

    void updatePseuEntryPosition (entry **pseuEntry, blastnEntry *blastnEntry, string *curChr, pseuInts **pseuInts);
    void endPseuEntry (entry **entry, string *chr, pseuInts *pseuInts);

So it's both the type and the variable. (I can't get the formatting to work for the comment, sorry)

Comment: What are the values of `scafStartPos and pseuPos` when `memset` is called?

Comment: Instead of using (*pseuInts) everywhere, you could just dereference the pointer once in at that start of function and put it in a local variable. If you actually change what it points to, set that before you return from the function. Your code is very hard to read.

Comment: @ryyker I tried using pseuInts.pseuPos and got an error that I was trying to access something not part of a struct or union

Comment: @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey They change in a different part of the code to correspond to the position in the long string where the next short string should be start and the last position added to the concatenated string, respectively.

Comment: @Seth_m55 Do you know what the actual values of `scafStartPos` and `pseuPos` are?  If they're both the same number, `memset` won't set anything, right?

Comment: @CharlieBurns I apologize for the confusion.  In the long execution of the program it will have 100,000+ short strings that range from 100 - 2,000,000+ characters in length.  I wanted to save as much memory as I could so I avoided as many variables as possible.  For the purposes of finding a solution though I'll work up a single dereferenced set of uniquely named variables and repost so it's easier to read.

Comment: @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey I made a debugging printf() to display all the pseuInt values and the values of the math I use in the memset() and realloc() calls.  I inserted it right at the start of the else if and it posted all the numbers of how many Ns should be set, but the Ns  didn't appear in another printf after the memset() call displaying the long string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***If you are okay with considering*** a completely different approach, I would like to offer this:

I understand your intent to be:  *Replace existing spaces between two strings with an equal number of "N"s.*  `memset()` (and associated memory allocations) is the primary method to perform the concatenations.

The problems you have described with your current concatenation attempts are :
***1)*** garbage embedded in resulting string.
***2)*** writing "N" in some unintended memory locations.
***3)*** "N" not being written in other intended memory locations.

***Different approach***:

***First:***  verify that the memory allocated to the string being modified is sufficient to contain results
***second:*** verify all strings to be concatenated are `\0` terminated before attempting concatenation.
***third:*** use `strcat()`, and a `for(;;)` loop to append all "N"s, and eventually, subsequent strings.

***eg.***

```
for(i=0;i<numNs;i++)//compute numNs with your existing variables 
{
    strcat(firstStr, "N");//Note: "N" is already NULL term. , and strcat() also ensures null term.
}
strcat(firstStr, lastStr); //a null terminated concatenation
```

***I know this approach is vastly different*** from what you were doing, but it does address at least the issues identified from your problem statement.  If this makes no sense, please let me know and I will address questions as I am able to.  (currently have other projects going on)

Comment: Sorry about the late reply.  I was double checking if my approach already did what you suggested and I was missing null terminators.  I've edited my code to ensure there is a '\0' after every string that is edited and it's working perfectly.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your memset:

```
memset (((*pseuEntry)->seq.str + ((*pseuEntry)->seq.len))), ...
```

That's the destination.  Shouldn't it be:

```
(memset (((*pseuEntry)->seq.str + ((*pseuEntry)->seq.len) + ((*pseuEntry)->seq.pseuStartPos))
```

Otherwise I'm missing the meaninging of `pseuInts` .

Comment: You may be onto something, currently though I believe OP's declared intent is to start inserting "N" at the end of seq.str + seq.len, for a count of scafStartOis-pseuPos (abbreviations).  I am looking at it in a very large screen with everything laid out, and it is still difficult to follow.  Some compilable code would help.

Comment: Sorry about the delayed reply.  ryyker's explanation is accurate.  I need to add enough Ns to fill the space from the last string that was added (held by pseuPos) to the start of the next short string (held be scafStartPos).  PseuStartPos is used when they positions overlap, IE if string X ends at position 5 and string Y starts at position 4 then I need to make a new long string and update pseuStartPos to be 4 instead of one so that all the relative positions are adjusted to that new start position.